# Cacti Migration

Tags: migration, cacti

I try to migrate Cacti from a server A to a server B.
Both are on Debian 6 and this is the same version of Cacti (0.8.7g)

I follow these steps :

1. Backup cacti db on server A
2. Disable Cacti cron on server A and B
3. Backup all rra (for i in `find -name "*.rrd"`; do rrdtool dump $i > $i.xml; done)
4. Copy in server B and convert from xml to rrd
5. Enable Cacti cron on server B

I see my previous graph but they don't refresh with the new datas.
Memory usage is 0 on my graph... The same for the number of process

How to reactivate Cacti ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you also rebuild the poller cache ?

Go to Console -> System Utilities -> Rebuild Poller Cache

That rebuilds the cache which the poller is using. It sometimes get's not updated properly during an update leaving some graphs empty.